# What is the difference between significant location and region change updates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

It's impossible to set desiredAccuracy for significant location change. I have tried and it returned default value 1414 for horizontalAccuracy. Does region change update method is better in terms of accuracy? Is it possible to set it and what is the maximum allowed accuracy for region change update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no accuracy for -monitorForSignificantLocationChange. It is a built in monitor that is designed to be used for broad updates, low on accuracy (but can be accurate enough depending on the application), and great on battery life. It works on the same principal as the -monitorForRegion method. It will update when it thinks you have moved a significant bit (e.g. cell tower transition, new wifi connection, etc). It will also steal/borrow location from other apps that use location as well. So it can be pretty accurate considering how it gets your location.

If you need precise location in the background... you are going to have to sacrifice battery life. The only other alternative is to sacrifice some location accuracy. In my experience, the location returned via the significant change and region monitoring is pretty accurate.

Region monitoring can take accuracy settings. But it mainly just comes off your -locationManager settings. Once you enter the background, you are at the mercy of the system again. I'm not 100% sure if your -monitorForRegion will retain the set level of accuracy, my guess is no. Mainly due to the restrictions on battery life. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I need to maintain and monitor a list of places using low battery consuming method like GSM. For this case, GPS is strictly forbidden. It would be sufficient to alert a user when he enters a zone with a 1-2 km radius (including errors and accuracy). I mean, 1-2 km radius zone is the real actual zone that I need to check that user is in. So, I would like to achieve maximum accuracy with GSM and I'm thinking about using desired accuracy with kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer (not sure about kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters that might be using GPS).

Comment: I tried using regions with 1000 m radius with kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer but that did not give me any updates when I was traveling from work to home ~ 3 km distance. Then I reduced region radius to 500 m and set desired accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation (GPS). Then I got the notiication. I'm struggling to guess what should be the best combination of region radius and desired accuracy values (GSM) that would work for all places over the world. The place will be some object in airports. Could you advice me if you have any suggestions?

Comment: Forgot to mention. I also tried setting 1 m radius for regions and used kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer. I though that would give 1001 km real zone tracking but that didn't worked out. So currently, I'm trying with region radius of 500 m and kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer. Have you tried with regions, what values have you used?

Comment: From what I know, the region monitoring doesn't use active GPS to get location... it borrows whatever is reporting back from the device during normal communication. Could be GPS from other app, could just be cell triangulation or wifi connection. I would think monitoring significant changes and or regions should be more than sufficient for 1-2km accuracy. Good luck.